# Numpy Double summation

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, scipy

[image]

[image]

My implementation is:

```
def getGaussianValue(x, mean, covariance):
    part1 = 1/np.power(2*np.pi, x.shape[0]/2)
    part2 = 1/np.sqrt(np.linalg.det(covariance))
    part3 = np.exp(-(0.5) * np.matrix(x-mean) * np.matrix(np.linalg.inv(covariance)) *  np.matrix(x-mean).T)
    return part1 * part2 * part3 
def getLogLikelihood(K, data, pii, mean, covariance):
    sum_i = 0.0
    for i in range(data.shape[0]):
        sum_k = 0.0
        for k in range(K):
            sum_k += pii[k] * getGaussianValue(data[i], mean, covariance)
        sum_i += np.log(sum_k)
    return sum_i
```

Here `N=150, K=3`,`X` is a `150x4`numpy array, `Covariance(Sigma)` is `3x4x4` numpy array and `mean(mu)` is `3x4` numpy array. How to make it faster?

Comment: Your log-likelihood states that mean and covariance depend on `k`, but the code doesn't seem to reflect that.

Comment: how slow is it? did you run `timeit` to compare different implementations?

Comment: Take a loot at : https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/mixture/gmm.py

Comment: There are several tools that available for profiling Python. You might look at cProfile (https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) or the Python line profiler https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler

Answer (score 3):

it's always a good idea to precompute everything that's possible and never calculate anything twice.

1. just invert the covariance once and store the inverted matrices
2. also precompute the normalization terms `part1` and `part2` only once rather than on every call of `getGaussianValue`
3. no need to calculate `np.matrix(x-mean)` twice (don't know whether numpy optimizes it anyway)
4. consider using numpy's builtins like `scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.pdf`